# Use one admob account with two google play accounts?

Tags: android, admob

I have my own google play developer account and admob account. 
I sold my app to a company. They want to use this app to promote their company products and services. So, I must publish the app to this company google play account. On their behalf, I want to include my own admob ad IDs inside this app.

I use this admob account with my own GP as well.

In short, can I use one admob account with two GPs?
Will google ban me for this?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can. The admob policies does not prohibit this. We have two google play accounts(one purely for apps and the other for games), both linked to one admob account and so far(4yrs) we've had no issues. However, if the app is suspended on the play store due to a violation, admob will disable ad serving

Comment: You just made my dayyy!  Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it in current policies.  Saying from experience,  Google may ban both of your accounts.